# array adaptor for list view throws null pointer exception

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to add list view in an array of Views. The null pointer exception is thrown at lv1.setAdapter. I don't know why it's happening.

Here is my code:

```
private ListView lv1;
 private String lv_arr[]= new String[]{"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};
```

---

```
View[] vs = new View[1];
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>    (MyCalendar.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lv_arr));
vs[0] = lv1;    
view.setListViewItems(vs);
```

---

here is the ListViewO1 inside list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: First accept previous questions.

Comment: I have just posted the parts that were relevant to the problem. I posted the xml part again as a comment coz after posting the question, I saw that it had been removed, and I thought it was because of character limit. But its there so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you setting your content view to list.xml?

```
setContentView(R.layout.list);
```

Accept correct answers as correct and more people are likely to help you!
( it's the greyed out tick on the left of a post (below the rating number), click it and it will go green to accept the answer ).

Comment: I have accepted the answers to my previous questions. And no, the content view is set to another xml that contains buttons only.

Comment: Ok, Got it. I placed listview inside the xml stated in setcontent view. Cheers.

Comment: I am able to add a textView to this view array but when I add this listview I m getting Illegal state exception saying the specified child already has a parent. you must call removeView() on parent first.